# Create an affinity to mouse and center of the screen with mouse move

Tags: javascript

I need the div to always look at the center of the screen and move along the mouse position with a small distance say 100px

- Mouse at left center - object should be more left of the mouse position and pointing center of screen
- Mouse at left top - object should be more left-top of the mouse position and pointing center of screen
- Mouse at right bottom - object should be more right-bottom of the mouse position and pointing center of screen

and similar for all other positions

I have written this small code but I am unable to cover all scenarios.
Only scenario that might be somewhat working is when you point at the top or right top of the screen

> Appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need more details

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  const deltaX = event.clientX - (myDiv.offsetLeft + myDiv.offsetWidth / 2);
  const deltaY = event.clientY - (myDiv.offsetTop + myDiv.offsetHeight / 2);

  const angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * (180 / Math.PI);

  const distance = 100; // Change this value to adjust the distance from the mouse

  const translateX = event.clientX - distance;
  const translateY = event.clientY - distance;

  myDiv.style.transform = `translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px) rotate(${angle}deg)`;
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transform-origin: center center;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Flashlight.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This seems more like a Math problem. Probably need to fix a point for the flashlight to directly point at the center and then from there do a 360 degree rotate for each mouse movement based on the x,y coordinates of the mouse. I'll need to try it out though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I have corrected the math. As mentioned earlier, The idea is to first point the SVG (flashlight) to the center of the page. Now calculate the angle from the center of the page to given set of coords based on it just rotate the correctly pointed SVG or flashlight.

Just FYI, I have removed the cursor and removed the scrolls for an in-depth effect.

```js
const centerX=window.innerWidth / 2;
const centerY=window.innerHeight/ 2;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  const x = event.clientX;
  const y = event.clientY;
  const deltaX = (centerX - event.clientX);
  const deltaY = (centerY - event.clientY);
  
  let angle = Math.atan(deltaY/deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
  if((x>centerX && y<centerY) || (y>centerY && x>centerX))angle+=180
  
  const distance = 50; // Change this value to adjust the distance from the mouse

  const translateX = event.clientX - distance;
  const translateY = event.clientY - distance;
  
  const extraRotationForSVG = 210;

  myDiv.style.transform = `translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px) rotate(${angle+extraRotationForSVG}deg)`;
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  cursor:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(-100deg);
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Flashlight.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
}
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```