# The mouse follower isn't moving

Tags: javascript, gsap

1. I set the values of the clamp as 0.8 and 1.2, and wrote out the entire code.
2. But after writing it all I just thought of changing the clamp values to 0.8 and 1.4. The mouse stopped moving strangely.
3. I brought back the values of .8 and 1.2 and again the mouse follower wasn't moving even after bring back the initial values.

I was expecting it to move obviously.

```js
function circleChapta() {
  var timeout
  var xscale = 1
  var yscale = 1
  var xprev = 0
  var yprev = 0

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(dets) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var xdiff = dets.clientX - xprev
    var ydiff = dets.clientY - yprev
    xprev = dets.clientX
    yprev = dets.clientY
    xscale = gsap.utils.clamp(0.8, 1.2, xdiff)
    yscale = gsap.utils.clamp(0.8, 1.2, ydiff)

    MouseFollower(xscale, yscale)

    timeout = this.setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("#circleScroll").style.transform = `translate(${dets.clientX}px, ${dets.clientY}px scale(1, 1))`;
    }, 100)
  })
}
circleChapta();


function MouseFollower(xscale, yscale) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(dets) {
    document.querySelector("#circleScroll").style.transform = `translate(${dets.clientX}px, ${dets.clientY}px scale(${xscale}, ${yscale}))`;
  })
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] and add relevant HTML, CSS and [CDN frameworks](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/gsap) to make is a [mcve]

Comment: Also give a overview of what you are trying to do for better understanding. Also you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278220/create-an-affinity-to-mouse-and-center-of-the-screen-with-mouse-move/76284796#76284796

Comment: Your code produces error: `gsap is not defined`. please supply the appropriate libraries or code used in them (`clamp`).

Answer (score 0):

`MouseFollower` is creating another event listener for mouse move for every time it is called, which is on every mouse move, instead of performing the translation on the circle inside it.

Removed the addEventListener inside it:

```js
function MouseFollower(xscale, yscale) {
    document.querySelector("#circleScroll").style.transform = `translate(${dets.clientX}px, ${dets.clientY}px scale(${xscale}, ${yscale}))`;
}
```